# Flash automatically names objects on stage "instance#"

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, instances

I have 2 TLF text boxes already placed on my main stage. In the property inspector window I give these the instance names: "txt1" and "txt2".

I am trying to have a single mouseup event, and figure out which text box it occurred on.

My document class has the following code:

```
package  {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

public class SingleEvent extends Sprite{

    public function SingleEvent() {
        // constructor code
        root.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, textChanged,false,0,true);
    }

    private function textChanged(e:KeyboardEvent){
        trace(e.target.name);
        trace("   " + e.target);
        switch(e.target){
            case txt1:
                trace("txt1 is active");
                break;
            case txt2:
                trace("txt2 is active");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Example output is:

```
instance15
   [object Sprite]
instance21
   [object Sprite]
```

Since the objects are already on the stage, I am not sure how to get flash to recognize them as "txt1" and "txt2" instead of "instance#". I tried setting the .name property, but it had no effect.

In the publish settings, I have "Automatically declare stage instances" checked.

Also, is it possible to have a single change event for multiple slider components? The following never fires:

```
root.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, sliderChanged,false,0,true);
```

Thanks for any tips

Comment: What version of Flash are you using?  Not that it should matter, but your code works completely fine for me.

Comment: Ahhh... I take it back.  I see you are using CS5, didn't notice the TLF factor in your question.  When I change from dynamic to TLF I get the same behavior as you do.

Comment: Yep CS5. That is weird it works for the dynamic text. I might have to change, and use that kind of text. However, I was using TLF because it looks crisper.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Flash Player hasn't initialized the TLFTextFields by the time the constructor is called.  Try this:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.describeType;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class TestTLF extends MovieClip {

        private function onEnterFrame (ev:Event) : void {
            removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
            for (var i:int = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
                var obj:Object = getChildAt(i);
                trace (obj.name + ":"+describeType(obj));
            }
        }

        public function TestTLF() {
            addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }
    }

}
```

You will find that in addition to the mysteriously created additional objects "__id#" and "instance#", both of your TFLTextFields are recognized.

Also, your Slider components obviously don't "bubble" their SliderEvents, which means they never reach the root object.  You can, however assign a handler function as many times as you want, so you could just add listeners to each of your sliders, all referring to the same `sliderChanged` function.